# With Doxygen 1.6.x, how to fix segfault crashes caused by \subpage circular dependencies?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

For various reasons, I'm stuck with 1.6.3.

I found that if Page A has a `\subpage` B reference, and Page B has a `\subpage` A reference. I get a segfault 11 when I generate the doc. Same for `\sa` if I ever use a subpage in `\sa` section.

Is there a way to fix this so that I can still cross-reference two pages?

Comment: I tried the following on windows (with 1.8.6 and 1.6.3):
/**
\mainpage Circular test

\page pg_a Page A
text page A with reference to B
\subpage pg_b

\page pg_b Page B
text page B with reference to A
\subpage pg_a
*/

And got the following message

Warning: page defined at line 4 of file aa.txt with label pg_a is a subpage of itself! Please remove this cyclic dependency.
Exiting...
Either I didn't catch the problem or some information is missing to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found out about it myself. The command I want is `\ref`.

Still, IMO there shouldn't be a crash when circular `\subpage` happens on Doxygen's part.